# Parsing Json in a ListView

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop a android app for Rally.
My ActivityClass:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_page);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        data_list = new ArrayList<>();
        load_data();
        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,data_list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void load_data()
    {
        String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
        String password = getIntent().getStringExtra("password");
        try
        {
            restApi=new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com"),username,password);
            QueryRequest userstory = new QueryRequest("HierarchicalRequirement");
            userstory.setFetch(new Fetch((new String[] {"Name", "FormattedID","Tasks"})));
            QueryResponse responseus = restApi.query(userstory);
            JsonArray userstory1 = restApi.query(userstory).getResults();
            for(int i=0;i<responseus.getResults().size();i++)
            {
                JsonObject storyJsonObject = responseus.getResults().get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                QueryRequest taskRequest = new QueryRequest(storyJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("Tasks"));
                taskRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Name","Actuals","Estimate"));
                JsonArray tasks = restApi.query(taskRequest).getResults();
                for(int j=0;j<tasks.size();j++)
                {
                    MyData data = new MyData(userstory1.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("Name").toString(),tasks.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("Name").toString(),tasks.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("Actuals").toString(),tasks.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("Estimates").toString());
                    System.out.println("User Story : "+storyJsonObject.get("Name")+" Task :"+tasks.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("Name")+" Actuals :" +tasks.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("Actuals")+" Estimate :"+tasks.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("Estimates"));
                    data_list.add(data);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException | IOException e)

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

AdapterClass:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<MyData> my_data;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<MyData> my_data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.my_data = my_data;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.userstory.setText(my_data.get(position).getUserstory());
        holder.tasks.setText(my_data.get(position).getTask());
        holder.actual.setText(my_data.get(position).getActuals());
        holder.actual.setText(my_data.get(position).getActuals());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return my_data.size();
    }

    public  class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        public TextView userstory,tasks,actual,estimate;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            userstory=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvUserStory);
            tasks=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTask);
            actual=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvActual);
            estimate=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEstimate);


        }
    }
}
```

Getters/Setters:

```
public class MyData
{
    private String userstory;
    private String task;
    private String actuals;
    private String todos;
    //getters/setters
```

Error Log:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.bmc.apetkar.akshay_rallyrest/com.bmc.apetkar.akshay_rallyrest.FirstPage}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String com.google.gson.JsonElement.toString()' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.String com.google.gson.JsonElement.toString()' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                         at
>   com.bmc.apetkar.akshay_rallyrest.FirstPage.load_data(FirstPage.java:72)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.bmc.apetkar.akshay_rallyrest.FirstPage.onCreate(FirstPage.java:45)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)

I am getting NPE in activity class load_data method.The data is being loaded at run-time.What could possibly be the reason for this.I need to know if there is something wrong I am doing while setting the data into the view or because some data issue.Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Should I post an Error log??

Comment: You posted a ton of code, but not the error log showing the error you want help with. Should make you think, doesn't it?

Comment: ...nor, for that matter, the offending JSON.

Comment: @Akshay the android studio log panel will show which line ( code line number) the exception was occurred

Comment: @Akshay From the error it is quiet clear that you are doing toString() on a null object. Debug the response and see which jsonValue is giving you null result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it.Made the following change.

```
QueryRequest us = new QueryRequest("HierarchicalRequirement");
            us.setFetch(new Fetch("Name", "FormattedID","Tasks"));
            JsonArray us1 = restApi.query(us).getResults();
            for(int i=0;i<us1.size();i++)
            {
                QueryRequest task = new QueryRequest((JsonObject) us1.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("Tasks"));
                task.setFetch(new Fetch("Name","Actuals","Estimate"));
                JsonArray tsk = restApi.query(task).getResults();
                for(int j=0;j<tsk.size();j++)
                {
                    MyData data = new MyData(us1.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("Name").toString(),tsk.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("Name").toString(),tsk.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("Actuals").toString(),tsk.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("Estimate").toString());
                    //System.out.println("UserStory : "+us1.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("Name")+"Task : "+tsk.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("Name"));
                    data_list.add(data);
                }
            }
```

I put both the responses in the Json Array.That did the job